# browser hijacker won't go away after deleting Vista

Tags: firefox, browser

I recently downloaded Ubuntu and deleted the old OS, windows vista, however, a browser extension called Frontier search has hijacked Firefox and I can't seem to remove it. Please help, all guides to removing it are for windows. It appears to be replacing the default search on both Firefox and chromium with frontier search, putting ads all over and stating that windows defender (without windows being installed) is trying to defend my PC from simple things such as YouTube.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! To better help us help you, please provide more information, such as what your problem is, what you are trying to do, what you have tried, and any error messages which you have encountered.

Comment: If that search engine is still around you didn't delete the old OS good enough. There's no way anything will survive a good format of the hard drive and Ubuntu offers to format the drive during install. Moreover I could only find references to Frontier search in relation to Chromium.

Comment: Do you use Firefox's Sync feature? Also, try creating a new firefox profile by running `firefox --ProfileManager`.

Answer (score 0):

wow never seen that happen in linux ,,,,,

easy way ,,,,,,export your bookmarks ,,,,,,remove firefox and chromium sudo `apt-get remove --purge firefox chromium` ,,,make sure the .mozilla folder got removed (I dont know where chromium keeps it's extensions) `ls -la ~/`   if you see a mozilla folder delete/remove it then reinstall firefox and chromium

their may be easyer ways like just deleting the .mozilla in your home DIR.

but this should work

Comment: Is this in the command prompt that I do this?